# Stylesheet of Office2007

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet, office-2007

Where from I get a stylesheet of Office 2007 Blue for my controls like button, Dropdown list, gridview etc for my ASP.NET Application.

Answer (score 0):

Office is a windows app and does not have anything like stylesheets!

I guess you are looking for something like the [Telerik ASP.Net Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx), they come with a skin that looks quite like Office 2007!